# 4TB-5TB External portable USB bus-powered hard drive that does not use SMR technology

Tags: usb, hard-disk, data-storage, portable, backup

Are there any currently manufactured 4TB-5TB external portable USB bus-powered hard drives that do ***not*** use [Shingled Magnetic Recording (SMR)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording) technology?

I would like to avoid SMR hard drives because I have read that they can be slow for non-archival functions.